# Passing arguments into an Assebly function

Tags: function, assembly, x86, att, frame-pointer

I'm trying to pass some arguments into a function but it doesn't get them correctly. I want to multiply some matrices and I want to pass: address of matrix 1, address of matrix 2, address of the matrix i want the result to be in, and the size of the matrix.

```
matrix_mult:
pushl %ebp
pushl %ebx
pushl %edi
pushl %esi
movl %esp, %ebp

movl 8(%ebp), %edi
movl 12(%ebp), %esi
movl 16(%ebp), %ebx
movl 20(%ebp), %ecx

*the rest of the algorithm*
```

After those lines, the values in `edi`, `esi`, `ebx`, `ecx` are all wrong.

The function calling looks like this - trying to multiply `matrix` by itself and storing the result into `matrix2`. The `matrix` and `msizze` are stored correctly.

```
main:
*reading msize and matrix*

pushl msize
pushl $matrix2
pushl $matrix
pushl $matrix
call matrix_mult
addl $16, %esp
```

In the debugger it shows me that:
`edi` = 2
`esi` = big negative value
`ebx` = big positive value
`ecx` = big positive value

Comment: You did `movl %esp, %ebp` after pushing some registers, but didn't adjust the offsets to still access your incoming stack args (which were originally at `4(%esp)`, then `8(%esp)` after one push, and higher after more pushes).  This is why we normally set up the frame pointer to point at the saved EBP, as a standard reference point.

Comment: so moving the `movl %esp, %ebp` before the pushes solves the problem